# Making reclassified raster layers automatically display break values in their attribute tables?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, table, reclassify

I am using `ArcGIS 10.2.` I have many raster layers which I need to reclassify (using the quantile method), I Also need to know the break values of these reclassifications.

I know that the break values can be viewed in the reclassify dialog box, however, due to the sheer number of layers I am dealing with, I do not have time to copy these values from this dialog box, before copying them again into the attribute tables of the reclassified layers.

Is there some way that I can have the break values automatically displayed as a field of the attribute table  belonging to the reclassified output?

Answer (score 2):

The process is straight.

1. Slice input raster using your method.
2. Add field to output table, say ULIMIT.
3. Use zonal statiststics as table and Join it to reclassed raster table .
4. Use field calculator to assign MAX from statistics to ULIMIT.
5. Remove join

Comment: Ok, that worked

Comment: Do you mind to mark it ' solved' please